# UITableViewCell set style programmatically

Tags: ios, uitableview

How to create UITableViewCell with an next style (**Right Detail** in xib)

[image]

For example can I use next:

*cell.style = 'Right Detail'* (roughly)

Thanks!

Comment: this might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174972/setting-style-of-uitableviewcell-when-using-ios-6-uitableview-dequeuereusablecel

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What you want is `UITableViewCellStyleValue1`, but you can't set an existing cell's style: you have to set it when you're creating it. Like this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"YourIdentifier"];
```

Comment: But what happens if you're using dequeueReuseable:forIndexPath:... on a tableView?

Comment: How is this done outside of the initWithStyle initializer?

Comment: Will this work ?

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:REUSEIDENTIFIER forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(!cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:REUSEIDENTIFIER];
    }

Comment: @fatuhoku check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/72728320/7734643

Answer (score 3):

While the best answer for this question is correct it doesn't touch on the topic of cell reuse.

It turns out you no longer have to use `tableView.register`. 
Instead you can use this approach:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // Whenever there's a reusable cell available, dequeue will return it
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier") ??
        UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `UITableViewCell` and style it programmatically then
Don't register it to your tableView and do this in `cellForRowAt`

```
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier)

    if cell == nil {
       var newCell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    // custom styling on textLabel, detailTextLabel, accessoryType
    cell = newCell
   }
```

Note: The deque method is without `IndexPath` param.

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TopCell", for: indexPath)
    cell = UITableViewCell(style: .value1, reuseIdentifier: "TopCell")
            
    var content = cell.defaultContentConfiguration()
    content.text = "Title"
    content.secondaryText = "Detail"
    cell.contentConfiguration = content

    return cell
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).