# Why UITableView does not call my customCell?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I've created UITableView and UITableViewCell programmatically. In my ViewController - `viewDidLoad` I do:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self
self.tableView.dataSource = self
self.tableView.registerClass(newsCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "newsCell")
```

later use it as:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("newsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! newsCell

    return cell
}
```

My `newsCell` class(shortly):

```
class newsCell: UITableViewCell {
    let scoreLabel = UILabel()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    print("init")

    self.addSubview(self.scoreLabel)
}
}
```

but I do not even get `init` on logs, so it does not call my custom cell at all. What is a problem?

Comment: I think you should move your initialization-code to the *init*-method instead of awakeFromNib().

Comment: Yes. I think so. `awakeFromNib` will be fire when you create from Nib File.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15239265/3981769

Comment: did u create the nib for tableviewcell ?

Comment: @longpham I'm trying this `init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
        
        self.initialize()
    }` but it gives me an error `Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UITableViewCell'`

Comment: If you have connected datasource and delegate to tableview on scoreboard then u don' t need to add self.tableView.registerClass(newsCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "newsCell")

Comment: @ReshmiMajumder I've created all programmatically

Comment: If you create the cell programmatically, `awakeFromNib` is never called, because there is no nib file. You need to use the designated initializer.

Comment: then awakeFromNib will never be called you need to use override func init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) then addSubview

Comment: @vadian like this `override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {` or?

Comment: Yes, like described in michael's answer.

Comment: PS: And you have also to initialize the `UILabel` with a frame. By the way: The naming convention suggests to use class names starting with a capital letter.

Comment: @vadian oh yes, you're right. I do not know why, but cell classes I call with lower case. I'll fix it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this code below:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: restorationIdentifier)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

and forced unwrapping is dangerous. You should do it like this:

```
if let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("newsCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? newsCell{}
```

Comment: Your answer isn't really in good condition. Maybe improve your sentences and code-editing.

Comment: sorry, my bad, i am not so familiar with tags of stackoverflow. i will never do this again,it is not professinal

Comment: oh my god!!!  sorry for my poor english ,  it is my second language,I  just learn it from american dramas.  I think i should be more careful about my next post..

Comment: Since you - the developer – have created the cell you are supposed to know that the cell definitely exists and you can forced cast the cell.