# detailtext label not showing up

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

When I am using the snippet below, the detail text label does not show up:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"NEW";
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath ];
    if(cell==nil)
    {     
    cell =  [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    }
    NSDictionary* item = [saleItems objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    cell.textLabel.text = [item valueForKey:@"name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text =  [item valueForKey:@"store"];

    return cell;




}
```

however when I modified the above method to the following the detail text showed up :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"NEW";
    [self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


    UITableViewCell* cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    NSDictionary* item = [saleItems objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    cell.textLabel.text = [item valueForKey:@"name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text =  [item valueForKey:@"store"];

    return cell;


}
```

what is going wrong in the first method ?
what is the correct way to use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier ?

Answer (score 2):

According to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174972/setting-style-of-uitableviewcell-when-using-ios-6-uitableview-dequeuereusablecel), registering `UITableViewCell` means all cells will be instantiated with the default style. Subtitled and right and left detail cells are not available with `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:`.

Answer (score 2):

Because you create a default style. Some method in your question is available from iOS 6. Are you sure you want to target iOS 6

You can try this example code (not only for ios 6):

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"NEW";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    // if you sure the cell is not nil (created in storyboard or everywhere) you can remove "if (cell == nil) {...}"
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary* item = [saleItems objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    cell.textLabel.text = [item valueForKey:@"name"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text =  [item valueForKey:@"store"];

    return cell;
```

}

hope this help you!

Answer (score -1):

In the second method, you are not de-queue-ing the cell but actually creating a new cell. This is not advisable. Instead, use the 1st method, but replace the line:

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath ];
```

with

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

This is because the method which includes the indexPath will always return you the cell, so the check;

```
if(!cell)
```

will always return true, and hence you will not able to create the cell with another style. But using the method without the index path will return nil, if the cell was not created before... You can read more on the UITableViewCell docs provided by Apple :)