# UITableView not loading cell data when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a UITableView setup on my View Controller using 1 prototype cell. When the view controller loads it queries my database (code removed for security reasons) uses CustomisationObject to create a new object and then stores that into an array.

When I run the app the 4 cells that are loaded have the correct values that are stored in localArray.

[image]

When I scroll down to see the remaining two cells, they are not been loaded, there values are blank.

[image]

Custom cell class

**CustomisationCell.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomisationCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *titleOutlet;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *sliderOutlet;

@end
```

**CustomisationCell.m**

```
#import "CustomisationCell.h"

@implementation CustomisationCell
@synthesize titleOutlet, sliderOutlet;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

Object Class

**CustomisationObject.h**

```
@interface CustomisationObject : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *localChannel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *localValue;

@end
```

View Controller Class

**CustomisationViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomisationViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate>

@end
```

**CustomisationViewController.m**

```
#import "CustomisationViewController.h"
#import "CustomisationCell.h"
#import "CustomisationObject.h"

@interface CustomisationViewController ()

@end

@implementation CustomisationViewController
NSMutableArray *localArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // SQL Code removed - query is return into variable resultSet

    localArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    while([resultSet next])
    {   
        CustomisationObject *customisationObject = [[CustomisationObject alloc] init];
        customisationObject.localChannel = [resultSet stringForColumn:@"COLUMN_ONE"];
        customisationObject.localValue = [resultSet stringForColumn:@"COLUMN_TWO"];
        [localArray addObject:customisationObject];
    }
    [database close];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [localArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CustomisationCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.titleOutlet.text = [[localArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] localChannel];
    cell.sliderOutlet.value = [[[localArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] localValue] intValue];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

If I change the height of the table view so all 6 cells fit on (no scrolling needed) they all load as expected. It only seems to be when the cell comes in and out of play.

Comment: Have you added a breakpoint in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to see what the  little rascal is up to?  I suspect you'll find `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` is returning `nil`, which is normal.

Comment: Also make sure `localArray` contains all the objects you expect it to contain - again breakpoint and look at the contents of this object.

Comment: Printing description of cell:
<CustomisationCell: 0x1191aff0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 35; 320 62); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x9f73e60>>

Comment: Cell does not seem to be returning nil. I've looped through localArray in viewDidLoad and all the objects are there.

Comment: If I change the height of the table view so all 6 cells fit on (no scrolling needed) they all load as expected. It only seems to be when the cell comes in and out of play.

Comment: I haven't used this new way of populating cell but this link mentions about registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: to use the method properly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174972/setting-style-of-uitableviewcell-when-using-ios-6-uitableview-dequeuereusablecel Hope this helps you

Comment: Can you share the implementation of `CustomisationCell`?

Comment: Added CustomisationCell.m implementation to question

Answer (score 0):

All sorted. It turns out the memory properties needed to be copy and not weak in CustomisationObject.h.