# detailTextLabel of cell does not show in swift 3

Tags: swift3, detailtextlabel

Although setting subtitle style for cell, but detailTextLabel has not still showed.

```
let cellIdentifier = "homeFeedItem"
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) ?? UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle,     reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
cell.textLabel?.text = self.arrItems[indexPath.row]["title"]
cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.arrItems[indexPath.row]["desc"]
cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: self.arrItems[indexPath.row]["icon"]!)
```

I tried print self.arrItems[indexPath.row]["desc"]. It's ok.
Please help me fix it.

Comment: Did you set the style in Interface Builder? Use the method `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:forIndexPath:)` to get always a valid non-optional reused cell.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I set it programmatically.

Comment: If you set it programmatically – which I don't understand why you make things more complicated  – you have to ensure that the style of all cells is set respectively.

Answer (score 0):

ok i got it. originally answered by [Scott Berrevoets](https://stackoverflow.com/users/751268/scott-berrevoets)

According to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13194320/2027018), registering UITableViewCell means all cells will be instantiated with the default style. Subtitled and right and left detail cells are not available with registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:.

Comment: Sure i set all.