# Swift - Error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value

Tags: uitableview, swift, ios8, xcode6

I have been making an app in Swift but I keep getting an error in my TableViewController class. I could not find any way to fix this and kept getting this error :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView?, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!  {
        let cell : TextTableViewCell = tableView!.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath : indexPath!) as TextTableViewCell

    let madan : PFObject = self.timeLineData.objectAtIndex(indexPath!.row) as PFObject

    cell.timestampLabel.alpha = 0
    cell.usernameLabel.alpha = 0
    cell.madanTextView.alpha = 0

    cell.madanTextView.text = madan.objectForKey("content") as String

    var dateFormatter : NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"
    cell.timestampLabel.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(madan.createdAt)

    var findSender : PFQuery = PFUser.query()
    findSender.whereKey("objectId", equalTo: madan.objectForKey("sender").objectId)
    var i = 1
    findSender.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if !error {
            let user : PFUser = (objects as NSArray).lastObject as PFUser // Error here

            cell.usernameLabel.text = user.username 

            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, animations: {

                cell.timestampLabel.alpha = 1
                cell.usernameLabel.alpha = 1
                cell.madanTextView.alpha = 1

            })
        }
    }    
    return cell
}
```

I cannot find any way to fix this.

Comment: Check the length of the objects array

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643522/fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if `objects` is coming back as `nil`. First check for nil:

```
if !error {
    if let actualObjects = objects {
        let possibleUser = (actualObjects as NSArray).lastObject as? PFUser
        if let user = possibleUser {
            cell.usernameLabel.text = user.username
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** I changed your `as` to `as?`. `lastObject` is already returning an Optional and so you might as well let the execution continue if the last object cannot be converted to PFUser. Also, because `lastObject` might return nil, you also need to check that for `nil`.

Comment: Thanks, the error is gone, but when I run the program the cell is blank. Is there a way to fix that

Comment: @Maanit you need to figure out why `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is returning nil for `objects`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this Error, must have to make sure one importing thing while declaration of Object :

```
var isActive: Bool?
```

`?` is the important to add, so now you can check `nil` values whenever you are, accessing this variable named `isActive` like below:

1. `if isActive == nil`
2. `if let _isActive = isActive as Bool?`

So [`Optional`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID330) values must be declared with the `?`.