# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional values

Tags: swift, xcode6

The following does not work. Here is what it tells me after the app crashes:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

```
class TeacherInputViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var textName: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var textEmail: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func btnSave(sender: AnyObject) {

        let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
        let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Teachers", inManagedObjectContext: context)          
        let newTeacher = TeacherObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

        newTeacher.name = textName.text
        newTeacher.email = textEmail.text

        context.save(nil)

        println(newTeacher)
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Why am I getting an error unwrapping an optional values?

EDIT:  this is the line it says is causing the problem:
let newTeacher = TeacherObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

Comment: It should indicate which line it's encountering that error on. That would be useful information for us to know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24715343/fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-value-in-swift)

Comment: context. save = (nil) ??? Ur saving nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unwrapped object must be `entity!` because it is the only unwrapped object in the function call. Your call to create the variable `entity` thus most likely returns nil.

1. Either you misspelled the entity name `"Teachers"` (looks fishy: why is it plural?),
2. or your managed object context is `nil`, in which case you have to go back to the app delegate and check why that is the case.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It was Teacher, not Teachers.