# Swift gyroscope yaw, pitch, roll

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, core-motion

I'm doing a project for my school, for a programming subject. I'm working in Xcode in Swift. I would like to make an application that uses Gyroscope. I don't know but somehow it won't run on my iphone because of some errors in Xcode that I don't know how to fix.When I run the program is says "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)"
The main thing of my project is to display rotations (yaw,pitch,roll) in degrees on iphone screen using gyroscope. I would be really grateful if someone help me with this. Thank you in advance.

The code in my ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import CoreMotion

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var currentMaxRotX: Double = 0.0
    var currentMaxRotY: Double = 0.0
    var currentMaxRotZ: Double = 0.0

    let motionManager = CMMotionManager()

    @IBOutlet var rotX : UILabel! = nil
    @IBOutlet var rotY : UILabel! = nil
    @IBOutlet var rotZ : UILabel! = nil

    @IBOutlet var maxRotX : UILabel! = nil
    @IBOutlet var maxRotY : UILabel! = nil
    @IBOutlet var maxRotZ : UILabel! = nil


    @IBOutlet weak var RollLabel: UILabel! = nil

    @IBOutlet weak var PitchLabel: UILabel! = nil

    @IBOutlet weak var YawLabel: UILabel! = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        if motionManager.gyroAvailable {

            if !motionManager.gyroActive {
                motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 0.2
                motionManager.startGyroUpdates()
                //motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc]init]; should I use this ???
                //motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.2;
                //motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates()

                 motionManager.startGyroUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue(), withHandler: {(gyroData: CMGyroData!, error: NSError!)in
                     self.outputRotationData(gyroData.rotationRate)
                     if (error != nil)
                     {
                         println("\(error)")
                     }
                 })      
            }
       } else {
              var alert = UIAlertController(title: "No gyro", message: "Get a Gyro", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
              alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Click", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
              self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


     super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // radians to degrees
    func radians(fromDegrees degrees: Double) -> Double {
        return 180 * degrees / M_PI
    }

    func outputRotationData(rotation:CMRotationRate)
    {
        rotX.text = NSString(format:"Rotation X: %.4f",rotation.x)
        if fabs(rotation.x) > fabs(currentMaxRotX)
        {
            currentMaxRotX = rotation.x
        }

        rotY.text = NSString(format:"Rotation Y: %.4f", rotation.y)
        if fabs(rotation.y) > fabs(currentMaxRotY)
        {
            currentMaxRotY = rotation.y
        }
        rotZ.text = NSString(format:"Rotation Z:%.4f", rotation.z)
        if fabs(rotation.z) > fabs(currentMaxRotZ)
        {
            currentMaxRotZ = rotation.z
        }

        maxRotX.text = NSString(format:"Max rotation X: %.4f", currentMaxRotX)
        maxRotY.text = NSString(format:"Max rotation Y:%.4f", currentMaxRotY)
        maxRotZ.text = NSString(format:"Max rotation Z:%.4f", currentMaxRotZ)

        var attitude = CMAttitude()
        var motion = CMDeviceMotion()
        motion = motionManager.deviceMotion
        attitude = motion.attitude


        YawLabel.text = NSString (format: "Yaw: %.2f", attitude.yaw)    //radians to degress NOT WORKING
        PitchLabel.text = NSString (format: "Pitch: %.2f", attitude.pitch)//radians to degress NOT WORKING
        RollLabel.text = NSString (format: "Roll: %.2f", attitude.roll)//radians to degress NOT WORKING
      }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: This post should be all you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643522/fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-values

Comment: Can you be more specific, because I'm a beginner. I don't know exactly where the error is or for which nil in my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In these two lines you're working with implicitly unwrapped optionals: you use them without `?` or `!`, but they'll crash your program if they're `nil`. In this case, `motionManager.deviceMotion` is `nil` because you haven't called `motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates()` prior to that access.

Your `viewDidLoad` method is the right place to do this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    if motionManager.gyroAvailable {
        motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.2;
        motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates()

        motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 0.2
        motionManager.startGyroUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.currentQueue()) {
           [weak self] (gyroData: CMGyroData!, error: NSError!) in

           self?.outputRotationData(gyroData.rotationRate)
           if error != nil {
               println("\(error)")
           }
        }
    } else {
        // alert message
    }

    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

There are a few additional changes there:

1. You don't need to call `startGyroUpdates()` before `startGyroUpdatesToQueue()`.
2. Swift uses [trailing closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-XID_160) for completion handlers like this one - nicer to write and read.
3. To avoid a reference cycle, declare `self` as `weak` inside a completion handler - this then requires using optional chaining when accessing `self`.

Answer (score 1):

"guard", "if let", and optional chaining are the key to safely unwrap optionals, here is a Swift4 answer:

```
let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if motionManager.isGyroAvailable {
            motionManager.deviceMotionUpdateInterval = 0.2;
            motionManager.startDeviceMotionUpdates()

            motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 0.2
            guard let currentQueue = OperationQueue.current else { return }
            motionManager.startGyroUpdates(to: currentQueue) { (gyroData, error) in

                // Do Something, call function, etc
                if let rotation = gyroData?.rotationRate {
                    print(rotation)
                    print(rotation.x)
                    print(rotation.y)
                    print(rotation.z)
                }

                if error != nil {
                    print("\(error)")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```