# Tableview found nil in iOS7 and works perfectly fine in iOS8

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am facing a strange issue. I am using `revealController` to open side menu for that as left view controller, I have placed a `tableView`.

I have placed `UITableView` in nib file of iphone and ipad and given `IBOutlet` to access it. In the `viewController` file I have given row height by simple line **`IBtblSideMenu!.rowHeight = IS_IPHONE ? 43 : 114`**.

Here at this point **`IBtblSideMenu appears to be found nil.`**
I have connected tableview's delegate and even placed controller's name in class field everything is done and it is perfectly working fine in iOS 8.
**`Issue comes in iOS7 only`**.

Please help me to resolve. I am not able to find any solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: did you try to debug it with method called or not? of tableview delegate? is there thirdParty code make any if condition with ios8 or ios7 some thing

Comment: There is third party code of pkreveal controller but i tried to debug as well. It was working perfectly fine before a month

Comment: please check related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643522/fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-values

Comment: @NitinGohel I have checked your given url in that during registering nib or accessing label issue comes but in my case UITableView is not available. It appears nil

Comment: Where are you placing the code for the rowHeight? Which method?