# Having issue calling delegate method and updating UI in the previous view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift-protocols

I want to use a delegate method to update some UI in my top view controller from the current view controller. I'm getting error `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. Please have a look at the following code and suggest what's wrong.

[image: First View Controller]

[image: Second View Controller]

Comment: Whether your delegate method called?

Comment: It's throwing error at         sampleProtocol!.updateTextLabel(someText)

Comment: Check some text is valid string or nill

Comment: I've printed it's value and it is a valid string.

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643522/fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-values

Comment: Can you show how you present your `SecondViewController` ?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I was missing `prepareForSegue` implementation in my first View Controller.

I had to assign the delegate to self in `prepareForSegue`.
I can't do it like

```
let vc = SecondViewController()
vc.sampleProtocol = self
```

which I was doing in my `viewDidLoad()`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the delegate like you're doing in your code in viewDidLoad. You have to implement prepareForSegue and set your delegate there.