# Swift - Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value

Tags: ios, swift

For some reason, Xcode is throwing an error when my code is run, saying

> "Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value".

The only problem is I am not unwrapping anything in this line of code that it says caused the error. AVAudioPlayer is a class, not a variable and so cannot be an optional.

Code:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    var label = AVAudioPlayer()
    var someSounds = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("EvilLaugh", ofType: "mp3")!)
    @IBAction func activation(sender: UIButton) {
        label = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: someSounds, error: nil) // This is where Xcode is throwing an error
        label.prepareToPlay()
        label.play()
```

Edit: The first possible duplicate question I did check prior to asking this question which did not solve my problem, but the second I did not find prior. Please feel free to remove this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643522/fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-values)

Comment: someSounds is probably returning nil because it cannot find the pathForResourcle for EvilLaugh

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [NSURL Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURL/fileURLWithPath:) the `fileURLWithPath:` is returning an optional value. And when you initialise the [AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioPlayer/initWithContentsOfURL:error:) the url argument is first unwrapped, in your case the url is `nil` and the application crashes.

For fixing this issue, you need to change your IBAction code like:

```
@IBAction func activation(sender: UIButton)
{
    if let someSounds = someSounds
    {
        label = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: someSounds, error: nil) // This is where Xcode is throwing an error
        label.prepareToPlay()
        label.play()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually when initalizing the *somesounds* variable you are **unwrapping** an optional :

```
var someSounds = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("EvilLaugh", ofType: "mp3")!)
```

So the someSounds variable might be nil at runtime.

Then when using the AvaudioPlayer initializer you're passing in this nil value, hence the RuntimeError :

```
 AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: someSounds, error: nil)
```