# Reloading UITableView shows error?

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray, tableview, uitableview

I am in a strange situation . when i try to reload the tableview using `reloadData()` it shows the following error . . .

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Here is the web service method that retrieves output

```
func didRecieveOutput(results:NSArray) { 
if results.count != 0 
{ 
userOrders = results as! NSMutableArray 
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in        
self.orderList.reloadData() })
 } 
}
```

Edit : I had checked my connection as well as delegate & datasource . It works fine with static data . But problem came when I called reloadData(). I had the same problem with static data as well as dynamic (data from server).

Comment: Show this link for better help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643522/fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-values

Comment: This mean that you put exclamation mark on nil value. Please provide some code

Comment: When you reload tableView, it might happen that your array become nil.

Comment: @CuteAngel actually my tableview object shows nil. The same happens when I try to reload tableview with static data.

Comment: may i know the reason for downvote vote ?

Comment: Then set proper IBOutlet in `nib` or programatically define tableview and alloc, init properly.

Comment: @CuteAngel pls check the edit and my answer

Answer (score 1):

There could be n number of reasons for this error. Some of the common causes are:

1. Your `@IBOutlet` for your `UITableView` is not properly connected.
2. Missing Delegate/Datasource could also be a reason.
3. Your model that feeds data to table views is being modified just before `reloadData()` call.
4. You are not properly checking for `nil` before using some objects.
5. Post getting server response, you are creating a new instance instead of using the one that was already loaded.
6. Another reason could be if your view structure is like this: UITableViewController ---> UIView ---> UITableView, then 'tableView' goes nil and you need to call out `[[self.view.subviews objectAtIndex:0] reloadData];`. Reference: [Apple Discussion Forum](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2636517?start=0&tstart=0).

You can try above cases but for us to pin point the error you would need to share your table view rendering code and flow.

Comment: It does not matter whether data is assigned to dictionary or array. For any further assistance from anyone on SO community you would need to share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Solution found !!!!
 :)

Thanks to [Abhinav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32694487/2613662) for giving me the thread even though his suggestion failed.

```
var array : NSArray = self.view.subviews
array.objectAtIndex(0).reloadData()
```

I got the same error for this also.
So I tried this and worked

```
var array : NSArray = self.view.subviews
array.objectAtIndex(2).reloadData()
```

Here in this array my tableview is at 2nd index. So my suggestion is to check the array to identify the tableview object first and use the index.