# FacebookSDK(4.7) Custom Login UI Button - Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, fbsdk

I am new to swift, How to resolve this error of optional **"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"**. This error occurs when i cancelled the Facebook login process.
[image: error in code]

Comment: It may helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24643643/988169

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error occurred because i was not handling the canceling event.

```
    @IBAction func FBAction(sender: AnyObject) {
            let fbLoginManager : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
            fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self, handler:{ (result, error) -> Void in

                if ((error) != nil){
                     // Process error
                }
                else if result.isCancelled {
                    // Handle cancellations 
                    //This method ; I should have implemented
                }
                else {
                    let fbloginresult : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult = result
                    if(fbloginresult.grantedPermissions.contains("email"))
                    {
                        self.getFBUserData()
                        fbLoginManager.logOut()
                    }
                }

            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change that line to an `if let` and if you fail that check it probably means you canceled the login process, since grantedPermissions were never...  granted!

In the `else` block handle when a user cancels the login process.  Hope this helped.

Comment: thanks but I know that it can be solved by if let binding but how? for Bool