# Format Int Array as String in cellForRowAtIndexPath Swift

Tags: arrays, string, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am taking time values stored in seconds in an Int array and attempting to put it on a UILabel which are then counting down trigged by a countDown function. I'm unable to get the time to count down in each cell, nor am I able to print the array without getting only the raw seconds value without formatting it as you'll see below. For now I can only display the raw value on a UILabel per cell as: `6532` (the hours, minutes, seconds)

I can't format the array either when trying to print it alone in the `for loop`as you'll see below. The array is stored as an Int.

When using a for loop in the countDown function, I can print to the logs the time formatted: `HH:MM:SS`. But not otherwise.

Here's my countDown function:

```
func countDown() {
    //timerInt is an array where I'm storing the Int values.
    for i in 0 ..< timerInt.count {
        let hours = timerInt[i] / 3600
        let minsec = timerInt[i] % 3600
        let minutes = minsec / 60
        let seconds = minsec % 60
        print(String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds))

        timerInt[i]--
        print(self.timerInt[i])
    }
}
```

I'm trying to do this in a cellForRowAtIndexPath method. The UILabel is located in a separate class:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cell


 //This is the first item i'm posting on a UILabel and it works fine.
    myCell.productName.text = productName[indexPath.row]

        /*This cell/label I'm unable to format like in the for loop 
          which is formatted as a string*/

         myCell.secondLabel.text = ("\(intArray[indePath.row])")

         /*how do I format the intArray here so that the time 
           appears HH:MM:SS?? */



    return myCell
}
```

How can I format the `intArray` so that it prints to the logs and to the UI as a formatted time (HH:MM:SS) like in the `for loop` when i print to the logs with the *String formatter*?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working for me with a lot of help from @vacawama:

1. This is how I'm querying the date, formatting how the date will be stored in the array and then placing it into an array called `intArray`.

   var createdAt = object.createdAt
               if createdAt != nil {

   ```
               let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
               let comps = calendar.components([.Hour, .Minute, .Second], fromDate: createdAt as NSDate!)
               let hour = comps.hour  * 3600
               let minute = comps.minute * 60
               let seconds = comps.second


               self.timerInt.append(hour + minute + seconds)


           }


           }

       }


        var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("countDown"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

   })
   self.tableView.reloadData()
   ```

   }
2. Second, I made sure to keep the `timer` variable outside of the query so that the timer doesn't count down based on how many objects I'm querying.
3. My countDown function did all the formatting:

   ```
   func countDown() {

       //timerInt is an array where I'm storing the Int values.
       for i in 0 ..< timerInt.count {

           let hours = timerInt[i] / 3600
           let minsec = timerInt[i] % 3600
           let minutes = minsec / 60
           let seconds = minsec % 60
      print(String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds))
         timerInt[i]--
           self.tableView.reloadData()

       }
   ```

   }
4. In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function, I formatted how the label should be displayed on the UI based on the array `intArray` as below:

   ```
      override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cell

      //Formatting how the cell will be presented
       let hours = timerInt[indexPath.row] / 3600
       let minsec = timerInt[indexPath.row] % 3600
       let minutes = minsec / 60
       let seconds = minsec % 60


     myCell.secondLabel.text = String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)

       }
   ```

Everything works perfectly and is displayed as wanted: HH:MM:SS.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function which will translated seconds into formatted string like

```
func formattedTime(seconds: Int = 0) -> String {
        let hours = seconds/3600
        let minsec = seconds%3600
        let minutes = minsec / 60
        let seconds = minsec % 60
        return String(format: "%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)
}
```

Once you have this method you can use this method inside the your `countDown` method along with `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
func countDown() {
    //timerInt is an array where I'm storing the Int values.
    for i in 0 ..< timerInt.count {
        print(formattedTime(timerInt[i]))
        timerInt[i]--
        print(self.timerInt[i])
    }
}
```

Inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you have `timerInt` as `Int` array where each index value need to be shown on cell `UILabel`

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! cell


     //This is the first item i'm posting on a UILabel and it works fine.
        myCell.productName.text = productName[indexPath.row]

            /*This cell/label I'm unable to format like in the for loop 
              which is formatted as a string*/

             myCell.secondLabel.text = ("\(intArray[indePath.row])")

             /*how do I format the intArray here so that the time 
             */appears HH:MM:SS??
        print(self.formattedTime(self.intArray[indePath.row]))
        return myCell
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm getting an error on these two lines in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` `myCell.secondLabel.text = ("\(intArray[indexPath.row])")` `print(self.formattedTime(self.intArray[indexPath.row]))` The error is that there was nil when unwrapping an optional value. Seems strange, unable to get rid of it...

Comment: @rinyfo4, please refer [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643522/fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-values) for error