# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: Swift - FMDB - executeQuery

Tags: swift, sqlite, fmdb

I am new to Swift, FMDB and development in general and I and I am getting a fatal error at runtime : `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional Value.` The error happens on the `executeQuery` line

Initial try and relevant code:

```
        var rightAnswer:FMResultSet?
        var memberDatabase:FMDatabase?
    ....
override func viewDidLoad() {
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("1_celebs", ofType: "sqlite3")
        memberDatabase = FMDatabase(path: path)
        if memberDatabase!.open(){
            print("database is ready")//it works if I comment out the stuff in loadquestion() 
        }
        else{
            print("error finding database")
        }
...
    func loadQuestion(){
        let querySQL = "SELECT Quote, Answer, answerNumber, Celeb1, Celeb2, Celeb3, img1, img2, img3, feedbackImg, Context FROM celebs WHERE answeredRight = 'no' ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1"

        rightAnswer = memberDatabase!.executeQuery(querySQL, withArgumentsInArray: queryParameters)
        rightAnswer!.next()
```

So then I tried this in func `loadQuestion()`

```
let results:FMResultSet? = memberDatabase!.executeQuery(querySQL, withArgumentsInArray: nil)
        while(results?.next() == true)
        {...}
```

Then I tried this:

```
do{
   rightAnswer = try memberDatabase!.executeQuery(querySQL, withArgumentsInArray: queryParameters)
   while rightAnswer!.next(){...}
 } catch let error as NSError {
    print("failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
 }
```

Then, this:

```
   do{
   let rs = try memberDatabase!.executeQuery(querySQL, values: nil)
    while rs.next(){...}
} catch let error as NSError {
  print("failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

and I get the same error on the `executeQuery` line every time! If I try to get away with getting rid of the exclamation and question marks  then I get an error on the console saying that the database could not be opened.

Comment: Check this out, it might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643522/fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `memberDatabase` is `nil`.

You should make sure you are populating that variable.

Another suggestion, you should avoid the force unwrap operator. It does bypass the compiler check for `nil` (or possible `nil`) values.

Swift does offer better solutions like

### Conditional Unwrapping

```
if let memberDatabase = memberDatabase {
    try memberDatabase.executeQuery(querySQL, values: nil)
}
```

### Guard

```
guard let memberDatabase = memberDatabase else { return }
try memberDatabase.executeQuery(querySQL, values: nil)
```

Comment: Can you please tell me the steps to make sure I am populating that variable? To be honest I am not 100% sure what that means.

Comment: @emilio: Unfortunately since I don't have the full code you are using I cannot be more specific. What I can tell you is that if you write something like `memberDatabase!.executeQuery(...` and `memberDatabase` is `nil` then you'll get a crash.