# Why just one of cells return nil?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, custom-cell

I've created custom cell and connected it as:

```
let cell: statisticsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! statisticsCell
```

and later I'm using it as:

```
cell.calendarLabel.text = recordsArray[indexPath.row].time
cell.dayLabel.text = "A \(recordsArray[indexPath.row].date)"
cell.amountLabel.text = "\(recordsArray[indexPath.row].count)"
```

but when I run my app, just this cell from those 3 - returns nil and crashes my app:

```
cell.dayLabel.text = "A \(recordsArray[indexPath.row].date)"
```

the value is not nil, I checked it.

Can anyone say me why it returns nil? Why just one label from 3 returns nil, while it's not nil?

**Crash**

It crashes with:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

on the

```
cell.dayLabel.text
```

Comment: from 3 means?row no - 3?

Comment: Please add more code,it will be helpful

Comment: 1. What is the crash log?  2. Explain in details, with less confusing terms. 3.What you have in recordArray?

Comment: @RohitKP no, there are 3 labels on my cell and I'm already added it to my question. So, this `cell.calendarLabel.text` and this `cell.amountLabel.text` are okay, but this one crashes `cell.dayLabel.text` even I add "AAA" text to it

Comment: @Vizllx I've updated my question, please look at it. The `recordsArray` is just an array, and it's not nil, as says on crash. I've checked it via `po recordsArray[indexPath.row].date`

Comment: try setting it to other label.do it cause crash

Comment: @RohitKP "it" - what? There is no problem with the data. The problem is with label

Comment: Post log response of  recordsArray here...

Comment: add a breakpoint cellForRow method--- an write in console "po cell.dayLabel" and show us the log of it

Answer (score 0):

See if you have created outlets properly for dayLabel and connected to the element in Storyboard.

Comment: I've connected it like those, other 2 labels.

Comment: try to redo once again . Bcz if the reference is not referring to an object on the UI and you  try to change the properties, It will also give similar errors . So better try to disconnect and reconnect  and lets see.

Comment: have you configured your custom class to the custom cell properly & try to see if the cell object is allocated

Comment: yes! Other 2 labels from the exact cell works perfectly! Just one does not!

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.calendarLabel?.text = recordsArray[indexPath.row].time
cell.dayLabel?.text = "A \(recordsArray[indexPath.row].date)"
cell.amountLabel?.text = "\(recordsArray[indexPath.row].count)"
```

As mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24643643/2714702) you can try this too:-

```
if let label = cell.dayLabel{
    label.text =  "A \(recordsArray[indexPath.row].date)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you check if the value is not nil? Make sure by logging in the console, right before you set it to `text` property of `dayLabel`, like this:

```
print(recordsArray[indexPath.row].date)
```

Also, the date - is it of String or NSDate type?