# how to avoid unexpectedly found nil?

Tags: ios, arrays, string, swift

Please help, I keep getting unexpectedly found nil.

I am very puzzled at how I can get around this?!

**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

I have tried the following but no joy:

```
        if (destinationNameArray == NSString(string: "nil")){
            destinationNameArray = [String]()
        }

        if (lineNameArray[indexPath.row] == "nil"){
            lineNameArray[indexPath.row] = "none"
        }
```

Comment: what is this line: `destinationNameArray == NSString(string: "nil")` intended to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643522/fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-values)

Comment: `"nil"` != `nil` and please add the code where the error occurs.

Comment: means you are force unwrapping an optional value (by using an "!") which has a value of nil (it is not a string btw)

Comment: ok so I have just done this to all my labels and I still get the error?!

           ` if let label1 = cell.tubeMode{
                label1.text = lineNameArray[indexPath.row]
            }`

Comment: I suggest to start with reading the Swift programming manual, right from the very start. The whole snippet seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use nil directly instead of "nil":

```
    if (destinationNameArray == nil){
        destinationNameArray = [String]()
    }
```

Comment: I tried this but it says value of [string] can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed

if (lineNameArray == nil){
            lineNameArray = [String]()
        }

Comment: `let lineName = object["lineName"].string as String!

lineName.append(lineName)`