# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value using core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I'm trying to use core data with my table view elements, but I get a runtime error: "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

here is the cellForRowAtIndexPath function and the function for maintaining the core data, I'm not sure which part of these has the error

```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! itemsList


        let shopList = people[indexPath.row]
        cell.items!.text = shopList.valueForKey("name") as? String


        return cell
    }

func saveName(name: String) {
    //1
    let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    //2
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("ShopList",
                                                       inManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

    let shopList = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!,
                                   insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedContext)

    //3
        shopList.setValue(name, forKey: "name")

    //4
    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        //5
        people.append(shopList)
    } catch let error as NSError  {
        print("Could not save \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
    }


override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    //1
    let appDelegate =
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext

    //2
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ShopList")

    //3
    do {
        let results =
            try managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        people = results as! [NSManagedObject]


    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

}

the breakpoint at this line

```
let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
```

Comment: this question is repeated in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643522/fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-values?rq=1

Comment: not really, my question is regard both table view and core data

Comment: itemsList is your custom cell type?

Comment: yes it is, do you think the problem because i'm using custom cell type?

Comment: There are multiple places where this could be crashing. The debugger should be stopping at the offending line. Please take a look at that with Xcode and report what you find.

Comment: can you post your crash log from your console and/or your stackTrace of crash? as @Feldur ask?

Comment: I edited my quesion

Comment: I forgot to choose using core data at the beginning when I created the project, I copy and paste related lines to my AppDelegate. is that the problem?

Comment: Check that`cell.items!`and the managed object context is not `nil`.

Comment: before    cell.items!.text = shopList.valueForKey("name") as? String check or rather add if(cell != nil) and add a breakpoint at same place to confirm the issue

Comment: Yes, your problem is most likely in the code you copy/pasted into the App Delegate.  Specifically check the model name specified in the `managedObjectModel` method.  The name must match the name of the .xcdatamodeld file in your project.  Post the App Delegate code if necessary.

Comment: Thank you pbasadf7, that's solved my problem