# Custom table view cell with swift in xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift, uiimageview

So, I created a custom table view cell with a label on the left and a UIImageView on the right.
The label has a tag of 100 and the UIImageView a tag of 110.

My code is the following:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ThemeCell") as UITableViewCell

    let theme = themes[indexPath.row]

    var themeName = cell.viewWithTag(100) as? UILabel
    themeName?.text = theme.themeName

    let themeImage = cell.viewWithTag(110) as? UIImageView
    themeImage?.image = UIImage(named: "test.png")

    //1
    //cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: "test.png")

    println("The loaded image: \(themeImage?.image)")

    return cell;
}
```

As is is, the themeName is displayed but the themeImage does not appear, although from println it seems that the image is loaded. If I uncomment the code in 1 the image appears in the custom cell but of course does not appear in the proper place as it is not added to the UIImageView that I created in IB.
Any ideas what I might be doing wrong? The Tags are all correct.
Thanks

Comment: I have a custom cell in IB so as to be able to add a UIImageView but I have not created a MyCustomCell class that extends UITableViewCell. I do not think I need to. I just need to have a UILabel and UIImageView.

Comment: Add the following code to see if your `UIImageView` can be displayed: `themeImage?.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170922/creating-custom-tableview-cells-in-swift/38470749#38470749

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firstly, you need to pin your views with auto layout mechanism. Open interface builder, left click on label inside your custom cell, then for example do the following:

1. Editor->Pin->Width
2. Editor->Pin->Height
3. Editor->Pin->Leading Space to Superview
4. Editor->Pin->Top Space to Superview

the same for image inside your custom cell

1. Editor->Pin->Width
2. Editor->Pin->Height
3. Editor->Pin->Trailing Space to Superview
4. Editor->Pin->Top Space to Superview

Then create custom class for your cell. for example

MyCustomCell.swift

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
}
```

Then set custom class for your cell and create connections from elements.

And now in tableViewController you can set the values to your elements without tags:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell: MyCustomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ThemeCell") as MyCustomCell

    let theme = themes[indexPath.row]

    cell.myLabel.text = theme.themeName
    cell.myImageView.image = UIImage(named: "test.png")

    println("The loaded image: \(cell.myImageView.image)")

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so the fault was not in the UITable at all but in the fact that the AutoLayout was not set correctly and the image appeared outside the tableview...