# UITableViewCell and Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list of type '(coder: NSCoder)'

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift

So Ive built a custom cell class for my `UITableView`. Xcode insists that this `UITableViewCell` has the following initializer (Xcode actually auto-fills this code for me):

```
class customCell: UITableViewCell {

    required init(coder aDecoder:NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

Ive modified the contents of this initializer to contain the following:

```
        // fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
```

If I remove the keyword `required` then Xcode kicks out an error and wants to correct me by putting the keyword back in.

So in my `UITableView` class I try to register this cell like so:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let coder: NSCoder = NSCoder()
    let customCell: AnyClass = customCell(coder: coder)
    table?.registerClass(customCell, forCellReuseIdentifier:"cell")
```

The penultimate line (the one where I initialize the customCell with the NSCoder, as Xcode wants me to) produces the error:

```
Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list of type '(coder: NSCoder)'
```

If I can I'd prefer to build my own initializer without an NSCoder.

If I try to use any other initializer then Xcode kicks out an error along the lines of:

```
Extra argument 'reuseIndenifier' in call
```

or

```
Missing argument in call
```

It will continue complaining until I am using the initializer with NSCoder. I am forced into using this initializer.

Please correct me if I am way off here, but to me it seems like I am caught in an catch 22 situation - Xcode complains if I build an initializer without a coder, and then when I try to use an initializer with a coder it complains that I am using a coder.

Despite this apparent contradiction I am fairly convinced all of this is a result of me being a dumbass somewhere.

Would anyone out there be kind enough to point me in the right direction?

Comment: did you read the UITableView programming guide?  afaik this isn't how you use UITableView and UITableViewCell's, but I may be wrong.  The initWithCoder initializer is called when using storyboards and that shouldn't happen because you typically initialize UITableViewCell objects in your UITableViewDataSource delegate method.  So perhaps a bit more context would help here.

Comment: I am trying to create a custom `UITableViewCell` programmatically - please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103278/creating-a-uitableviewcell-programmatically-in-swift

Comment: can you try using `init(style style: UITableViewCellStyle,
reuseIdentifier reuseIdentifier: String?)`, like I said, initWithCoder is called by interface builder

Comment: I tried this initially. Xcode complains that there is no `required init(coder aDecoder:NSCoder)` method and auto-completes it. Is this another Xcode bug? It has been suggested to me that I re-install Xcode.

Comment: making sure your IDE is working properly might be a start though I'm not sure that would solve your problem in particular. So leave the initWithCoder there, but just use initWithStyle

Comment: I try to use initWithStyle and Xcode insists that I use the NSCoder initializer. I cannot seem to get around it. Is Xcode forcing me to use the NSCoder initializer because it has the `required` keyword?

Comment: You need to call `
registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:
` to register your class in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: @MikePollard I am calling that later in the code, but that's not what is giving me errors or problems.

Comment: Sure, but you do that and then you don't need to do any of this `let coder: NSCoder = NSCoder()
    let customCell: AnyClass = customCell(coder: coder)`

Comment: @MikePollard i am just breaking the problem down, doesnt matter if I declare the custom cell first, then add it into `.registerClass(customCell,forCell....` or if I declare the custom cell inside that function like `.registerClass(customCell(),forCell...` - I get the same circle of errors, either that I am not initializing with an NSCoder or that I am using an NSCoder to initialize. Ive edited my question so you can see what I mean.

Comment: The problem is confusion between a class and an instance. You register the class, not an instance of it. `table?.registerClass(customCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"cell")`

Comment: @MikePollard this seems to have worked for me! Xcode still insists on this custom cell having a initializer that uses an NSCoder, but half the problem has gone away. Thanks for clearing this up - I was confusing instances with classes - if you add this solution as an actual answer I will mark you as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the `class` itself not an instance of it.

eg.

`tableView?.registerClass(customCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier:"cell")`

The issue with requiring `init(coder aDecoder:NSCoder)` is a separate one and discussed here: ['required' initializer 'init(coder:)' must be provided by subclass of 'UITableViewCell'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081287/required-initializer-initcoder-must-be-provided-by-subclass-of-uitablevi?rq=1)