# Some seemingly useless cruft when deriving from UINavigationController in swift

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, swift2

Why do I need so much (seemingly useless) pass through code that objc did not
require in a similar derivation:

```
class myNavigationController: UINavigationController {

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}
...
```

repeat ad nauseam for every single view controller of mine loaded from xib.

Comment: In the case above, is it necessary to override the init function if the only thing you do in your init is to call the super?

Comment: Right. That's exactly what I'm asking: why I'm required to write an essentially a noop. To avoid some hack/kludge in swift frontend maybe? I'd rather not have to guess

Comment: My question was if you cant just remove your override if you know that it will only contain the super.init? (And it's really a question, haven't tried it myself for this example :) )

Comment: (if you remove your override init(...) and just use your super's view by default, you can also remove the required init?(:NSCoder) )

Comment: No. You can't remove both of them. If you do that you will get something like .../myExtendedSessionNavigationController.swift:19:1: 'required' initializer 'init(coder:)' must be provided by subclass of 'UINavigationController'

Comment: I know cause I've just tried. Have you?

Comment: removing init(let rootViewController: UIViewController) {
  super.init(rootViewController:root)
 } along with the other two take care of this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should not be an issue if your don't want to overload the designated initializer `init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?)` your `UINavigationController` subclass. If you just want to make use of the default (super) initializer, you can remove both those methods from your class.

I.e., the following class

```
// MyNavigationController.swift
import UIKit

class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // I don't want to make use of this ...
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // ... nor this
    }

    // Things I do want to do with my nav. controller
}
```

can be reduced to

```
// MyNavigationController.swift
import UIKit

class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    // Things I do want to do with my nav. controller
}
```

Without any errors. (Verified in Swift 2.0, Xcode 7.2, simulator: iOS 9.2). This is expected behavior, see e.g. the accepted answer in thread ['required' initializer 'init(coder:)' must be provided by subclass of 'UITableViewCell'`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081287/required-initializer-initcoder-must-be-provided-by-subclass-of-uitablevi).

If you still get an error when removing these for this subclass type, please give some details regarding your use of the class / Xcode version etc.