# Everytime I scroll cell.viewWithTag will give fatal error while unwrapping found nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, viewwithtag

I have a table view with cells everytime I scroll I get fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

And it wil mark this code green: `let button = cell.viewWithTag(1009) as! UIButton`

```
  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{ 
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ChecklistItem") as! UITableViewCell 
  let label = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as! UILabel 
  let button = cell.viewWithTag(1009) as! UIButton 
  button.tag = indexPath.row        
  ...
 }
```

Comment: Please add your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method code along with question body, for better understanding.

Comment: `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ChecklistItem") as! UITableViewCell
            
            
            
            let label = cell.viewWithTag(1000) as! UILabel
            let button = cell.viewWithTag(1009) as! UIButton


            button.tag = indexPath.row`

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem, I already had the brackets and also a return statement. This is just the same...

Comment: Then in your case, I would suggest to use custom cell class rather dealing with tag values. Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170922/creating-custom-tableview-cells-in-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding this if-clause:

```
  if button == nil{
        println("Do nothing");
    }else{
        button!.tag = indexPath.row

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

get fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value caused you get button from viewWithTag after you set tag

```
let button = cell.viewWithTag(1009) as! UIButton
```

> ```
> **button.tag = indexPath.row**
> ```

So did not updated button tag, pass required information in button accessibilityIdentifier

```
let button = cell.viewWithTag(1009) as! UIButton 
button.accessibilityIdentifier = "\(indexPath.row)"
```

after Get button information by

```
let indexRow = Int(button.accessibilityIdentifier!)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it by (optionally binding) 'if let' or 'Guard let'

```
if let button : UIButton = cell.viewWithTag(1009) as? UIButton{
button.tag = indexPath.row

// your code...

}else{
print("Do nothing");
}
```