# Data not showing in custom tableview cell in swift have added the cell class below

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, cells

I have tried everything possible but I still can't figure out why the data is not shown in a custom cell. It looks fine in a `subTitle` cell and `println` confirms the data is there. I have checked the identifier and the `IBOutlets` a 100 times:

```
//  ActivityDetailsTableViewController.swift
//  TestActForm
//
//  Created by Jeremy Andrews on 2015/08/08.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Jeremy Andrews. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ActivityDetailsTableViewController: UITableViewController
{

    var activities: [Activity] = activityProfile

    override func viewDidLoad() 
    {
        super.viewDidLoad() 
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() 
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int 
    {   
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int 
    {
        return activities.count
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
        -> UITableViewCell 
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ActivityDetail", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ActivityDetailCell
        let activity = activities[indexPath.row] as Activity
        println(activity.question)
        cell.questionLabel?.text = activity.question
        cell.answerLabel?.text = activity.answer
        println(cell.questionLabel.text)
        return cell
    }

}

import UIKit

class ActivityDetailCell: UITableViewCell 
{
    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var answerLabel: UILabel!


    override func awakeFromNib() 
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) 
    {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cell.questionLabel?.text = activity.question
cell.answerLabel?.text = activity.answer
```

this code would fail silently if these label are not created. I bet you did not hook them up via IBOutlets in your storyboard.

Comment: Thanks for the comments so far - but still stuck. What I don't understand is that the println in this section of code shows clearly that cell.questionLabel?.text  and cell.answerLabel?.text has the required data

cell.questionLabel?.text = activity.question
  cell.answerLabel?.text = activity.answer
  println(cell.questionLabel.text)
  return cell

Comment: Have added it at the end of the original post

Comment: I am still convinced that you did not hook up the labels in the storyboard with the iboutlets in your cell class. What happens if you write `cell.questionLabel!.text = activity.question` instead of `cell.questionLabel?.text = activity.question`. If it leads to a crash it proves the label is never created.

Comment: I am also convinced its to do with the IBOutlet and I am re-working everything now and will try your suggestion.
I have a similar App  table from a web tutorial which works fine and I further note that  if I pout a blank label in this cell it shows up  without being linked. 
In the problem table this does not happen so it would to have something to do with custom cell.

Comment: did you try to crash it, as I said? this would ultimately prove that your labels are not existent.

Comment: No but I found the solution and have answered my question. Thanks for the input - it was a case of Xcode setting negative margins for some reason

Comment: I-m having the same issue...I hooked the outlets but on the cell class....where else should I create them??

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to everyone who gave suggestions - after 2 days struggle I finally found the solution thanks to: [creating custom tableview cells in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170922/creating-custom-tableview-cells-in-swift).

All you have to do is go to file inspector - uncheck size classes - there will be warnings etc.run and there is the data - strangely - go back to file inspector and check "use size classes" again, run and all data correctly reflected. Seems like in some cases the margin is set to negative.
A thought - if println( cell.nameLabel.text) shows your data is there then it is, check margin or put labels in the centre as a trial.

I noticed before that the story board had a highlighted area that did not match the cell boundaries - this actually showed the boundaries that run would use. A bug I think

Answer (score 1):

Use a breakpoint in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and check cell, outlets, model.
Also check if you set the delegate, datasource and outlet for the table.

Comment: derp, this made me realize I hadn't set the delegate/datasource for the tableview...