# UILabels and custom UITableView cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, class

I created a custom UITableView cell in my storyboard. Previously I used the "Subtitle" style for the cell, but I am now using a custom design made up with 2 UILabels.

How can I access these UILabels now? Before I used these two custom UILabels I would just use:

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)


 cell.textLabel?.text = pollContent 
 cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateString
```

in the

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {}
```

method

but since the cell style is now set to "custom" I can't really do that anymore. 
The problem I have is that I don't really know how I could use IBOutlets to connect these two UILabels to my ViewController class somehow?

I also created a custom UITableViewCell class and connected the UILabels to that but how do I get the UILabel content for each cell from the ViewController?

UPDATE:
So i cast the cell with my custom UITableViewCell now, and I added the following lines of code to my class:

```
    self.textLabel = titleLabel
    self.detailTextLabel = subTitleLabel
```

where titleLabel and subTitleLabel are both of my UILabels.

However I get the error message that .textLabel and .detailTextLabel are both get-only properties.

**UPDATE 2:** 
Thanks for all of your answers/suggestions. As you can probably guess, I am still a novice at programming!

I'll come back when I fix my problem.

UPDATE 3: Again, thanks for your help! It finally works now.

Comment: 1.You need to create a UITableViewCell class. Add Your IBOutlets to this custom class. Set the Cell claa

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating custom tableview cells in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170922/creating-custom-tableview-cells-in-swift)

Comment: None of these solve my problem @AlessandroOrnano

Comment: You simply need to set tags for your labels. Then get them by ’[cell viewWithTag:tag]’

Comment: @efimovD but aren't these tags only supposed to work for UIViews?

Comment: Man, uilabels are their subclasses) they inherit this property. You will simply need to cast

Comment: I added the answer to show what I mean. You can set tags from IB in property inspector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the cell as your custom Cell.

```
 let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? CustomTableViewCell


 cell.customLabel1.text = pollContent 
 cell.customLabel2.text = dateString
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I must be missing something, the UILabels still just display the default text.

How would the cell know that textLabel and detailTextLabels are referencing my UILabels?

Comment: Make sure your cell in Storyboards is set as the custom cell. Then you create outlets to the file for the custom cell.

Comment: .textLabel and .detailTextLabel are both get-only properties.

Comment: Please post your full custom cell file.  You should not have to to self.titleLabel etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110418/discussion-between-rmickeyd-and-user3545063).

Comment: @rMikeyD messaged you back!

Comment: @user3545063 I just updated this answer (waiting for peer review). The code showed that you should use cell.textLabel? and cell.detailTextLabel?. Calling that would still show the text in the cell's default labels which you can't see because your cell is set to "Custom" and you don't get an error because textLabel and detailTextLabel are not force unwrapped (has ? instead of !). You will need to use cell.customLabel to access the custom label's text. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @DanL, I could already solve the problem with rMickeyD 's help. And yes, this was the actual fault that caused the errors. I just didn't know that you could directly reference the custom UILabels (that were declared in the UIViewTableCell) in the ViewController. It works, because the cell gets casted by the custom viewtablecell and I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

1.You need to create a CustomUITableViewCell class that extends the UITableViewCell.

2.Add Your IBOutlets to this CustomUITableViewCell.

3.Set the Cell class as your CustomUITableViewCell that you just created in your storyboard.

4.change this

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CustomUITableViewCell 

    cell.textLabel?.text = pollContent 
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dateString
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
self.textLabel.text = titleLabel
self.detailTextLabel.text = subTitleLabel
```

For setting text insinde these labels.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you must set cell identifier also in the **Attribute Inspector** :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set some unique values to your uilabels tag property.

Get them later in

> cellForItemAtIndexPath

like so:

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:yourTagNumber];
```

BTW: Don't try to assign textLabel and detailTextLabel when the style of your cell is `Custom`. They are available only if style is `Subtitle`. Otherwise, they are nil.