# Different Cell in TableView Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cells

As a beginner, I'm trying to work with `UITableView` and `IOCollectionView`, How can I create different cells (some cells have a collection View and some cells have text or image only,...) in the same container?

For example: the Appstore, the cell on the top is a banner, containing  wide Collection View, second cell containing a category a the others containing label or button.

I work with swift 3 and prefer to use storyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you do know how to create your custom cell (if you don't check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170922/creating-custom-tableview-cells-in-swift)) and implementing the required data source methods, you should do this in `cellForRowAt` or `cellForItem` methods -I'm using `cellForRowAt` in the code snippet-:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // first row should display a banner:
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let bannerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BannerTableViewCell") as! BannerTableViewCell

            // ...

            return bannerCell
        }

        // second row should display categories
        if indexPath.row == 1 {
            let categoriesCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoriesTableViewCell") as! CategoriesTableViewCell

            // ...

            return categoriesCell
        }

        // the other cells should contains title and subtitle:
        let defaultCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoriesTableViewCell") as! TileAndSubtitleTableViewCell

        // ...

        return defaultCell
    }
```

**Make it more readable:**

you can also define `enum` for checking the `indexPath.row` instead of compare them to ints:

```
enum MyRows: Int {
    case banner = 0
    case categories
}
```

Now, you can compare with readable values:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // first row should display a banner:
        if indexPath.row == MyRows.banner.rawValue {
            let bannerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BannerTableViewCell") as! BannerTableViewCell

            // ...

            return bannerCell
        }

        // second row should display categories
        if indexPath.row == MyRows.categories.rawValue {
            let categoriesCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoriesTableViewCell") as! CategoriesTableViewCell

            // ...

            return categoriesCell
        }

        // the other cells should contains title and subtitle:
        let defaultCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoriesTableViewCell") as! TileAndSubtitleTableViewCell

        // ...

        return defaultCell
    }
```

Comment: tks you so much, i'll try it now