# How do I reset tableview's contents height after hidden UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[image]

Hi I'm trying to resize tableview's height after hidden indicatorView.

```
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.refresher.endRefreshing()
        self.indicator.stopAnimating()

        self.indicatorView.isHidden = true
```

When I set indicatorView as hidden but TableView's height still has space of indicatorView's height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, You need to implement [tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614998-tableview). For example:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    // pseudo:
    /*
     if a condition related to hide the indicator (for example response from calling an api to get some data) is true, retrun -for example 100-, else (the response has not been called yet) retrun another value.
     */
}
```

You can also check the `indexPath.row` for chaning a specific row height:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    // check if it is the second row:
    if indexPath.row == 1 {

    }
}
```

So, after calling `self.tableView.reloadData()` it should be called and assign the new height for the row.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Thanks~! It helps me a lot

Comment: Glad to help. You might want to check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39957187/different-cell-in-tableview-swift-3/39957982#39957982) of how to display different cells in the same tableview.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try this and update result in here! :)

Answer (score 1):

Embed `tableView` and `indicatorView` in a stackview.

Like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40643051/1457385), but with `Vertical` Axis.

Comment: Thanks for reply ~!