# Adding UIbutton programmatically to cell which inside table view. data massed up with other cell after scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

When the app first build, it seem like working just fine, please see pic where each pics is one cell in side the table view [image]  [image][image] . (I am working to place them properly)
The problem that I am facing is that: once I scroll down  and scroll up again. Each cell data got massed up. Please see pics. Which I still have no idea what is wrong in my coder after hours searching online and decoding. please point out what I am missing. I have attached my code. 
I am using the tutorial code from [Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/129059/self-sizing-table-view-cells)  and adding the codes below in the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` method Yes I am doing it each word as UIBotton to trigger an action. 
 Adding

```
 "cell.contentView.subviews.filter { $0 is UILabel }.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }"
```

didn't solve the issue. please give me a completed example?(working one) Thank you.

[image]

```
 let wholeSentense = artist.bio
    let whoeSentenseArray = wholeSentense.components(separatedBy: " ")
    var xPos = CGFloat(0)
    for element in whoeSentenseArray {
    var button = UIButton()
    button.setTitle(element, for: UIControlState.normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)


    let buttonTitleSize = (element as NSString).size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15 + 1)])
    button.frame.size.height = buttonTitleSize.height * 1.5
    button.frame.size.width = buttonTitleSize.width
    button.frame.origin.x  += xPos
    xPos = xPos + buttonTitleSize.width + 10


    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: UIControlEvents.touchDown)
    cell.addSubview(button)

    }


    return cell
  }
  func buttonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
    print("\n\n Title  \(String(describing: sender.titleLabel?.text))  TagNum    \(sender.tag)")
   // print("Button tapped")
  }
```

[image]  [image]

---

Comment: Table cells are reused. If you keep adding views to the cell when you dequeue it, they'll just overlay one another each time that cell is reused.

Comment: @particleman, How should I implement them to achieve my goal, where I can scroll the cell and each cell with the expected data?

Comment: The most common approach would be to define the cell UI in a Storyboard or a XIB, so that all of the UI elements are initialized and connected by the system. You should keep `cellForRowAt:` as lean as possible: just populate your cell with data, don't try to build it.

Comment: @particleman for this particular goal in mind, don't think using a Storyboard is a good idea to achieve the requirement.

Answer (score 1):

I think you better move this complicated logic into a `UITableViewCell` subclass. Here's a rough skeleton:

```
class MyCustomTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    var sentence: String! {
        didSet { <add your logic here> }
    }
}
```

There are lots of resources on SO and other websites about how to create custom table view cells, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170922/creating-custom-tableview-cells-in-swift).

Anyway, whichever way you choose to do it, you need to be aware that table view cells are reused. You need to first remove all labels before adding them:

```
cell.contentView.subviews.filter { $0 is UILabel }.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
```

Comment: adding the code of " cell.contentView.subviews.filter { $0 is UILabel }.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() } " doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: @StackExangeLearner you should put it right before the code snippet you showed in the question.

Comment: doesn't solve the issue?  Do I need to use the subclass logic to make it to work? I am avoiding it now since I need to make it working first then clean up.